# Maintaining a reference to an NSFormatter in a view-based NSTableViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsformatter

I have a project that currently uses cell-based NSTableViews WITH bindings. I am updating the project to use views instead. With cells, I could instantiate a NSFormatter in code, add it to an NSTableColumn's datacell's formatter property, maintain a reference to that formatter, and change the formatter's properties programmatically. I don't see a strategy to do the same thing with view-based tableviews.

With view-based tableviews, I can set a formatter on a prototype views' textfield, but that formatter is a prototype as well. This formatter will be instantiated several times so I can't maintain a reference to a prototype formatter. As another solution, I created a custom formatter object with my formatter's class, dragged my tablecellview's outlet to the formatter, but this doesn't work at all.

I need to be able to programmatically adjust how my formatter works in a view-based tableview.

Comment: Maybe a custom subclass of `NSValueTransformer` is an option.

Comment: Or maybe set the formatter in the delegate's `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method.

Comment: That's the ticket. I assumed that delegate calls and bindings were mutually exclusive. With the delegate call, I simply set the textfields formatter and do not specify a string value on the textfield. After the delegate call, the table view bindings populate the textfield's string value. Make an official answer and I'll accept it

Comment: An NSValueTransformer is an option, but it is a singleton and my application is document based so I would need to know in the NSValueTransformer the context of who was calling the formatter.

Comment: Bindings and dataSource are mutually exclusive (with exceptions). Bindings and delegate aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the formatter in the delegate's `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method.